# Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 at x.main

Tags: java

I'm a java beginner and since I have been started learning i have been facing the error every time I try to run an program which takes input from the user not only with the loops. The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 at x.main
```

Comment: Without seeing the corresponding part of the code, it is hard to say what exactly is wrong here - It seems you have an empty array but trying to read its first element

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the array of zero length (0-capacity). At the same time you are trying to access the first element of that array (in arrays the first element has the index `0`).

This is why you are getting such exception. Because your array of zero-size does not have even first element.